# Pytorch log normalisation calculation

Tags: python, pytorch, probability

I do not understand how Pytorch does Log normalisation and searching around I can not find a good example/explanation. Can someone provide an explanation please?

eg

```
input_tensor =torch.tensor([0.6,0.4])
m = dist.Categorical(logits = input_tensor)
print(np.log(input_tensor))
print(m.logits)

gives: 
tensor([-0.5981, -0.7981])
tensor([-0.5108, -0.9163])
```

My probabilities sum to one so there is nothing to normalise yet Pytorch is transforming my input.

The documentation for Pytorch says:

*The logits argument will be interpreted as unnormalized log probabilities and can therefore be any real number. It will likewise be normalized so that the resulting probabilities sum to 1 along the last dimension. logits will return this normalized value.*

https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/distributions.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `np.log` function calculates the value by the expression

[image],

Hence, if the input value is `[0.6, 0.4]`, the resulting output would be `tensor([-0.5108, -0.9163])`.

When dealing with `Categorical`, you can explore the PyTorch `categorical.py` source code here: https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/main/torch/distributions/categorical.py).

You would find a line of code:

```
self.logits = logits - logits.logsumexp(dim=-1, keepdim=True)
```

Considering your input tensor as `[0.6, 0.4]`, so the value of `logits.logsumexp(dim=-1, keepdim=True)` is

[image]

Therefore, that is why `m.logits` yields `tensor([-0.5981, -0.7981])`.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know we could look into the function code that easily